# Tricky CSS Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need a piece of CSS code (or a crafty hack) that will specify the width of a drop-down DIV on a product page to a width of 436 pixels:

http://warehouse.haddrellspoint.com/product/calcutta-can-bottle-coolers-149252-1.htm

(Click on 'Select Options' under the product price to view the problematic DIV)

The class name of the troublemaker DIV is 'ddChild'. However, any and all CSS declarations I've come up with to modify its width have been ignored.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Disclaimer: This page's HTML code is sourced from a built-in template, so I have little control over the way the page and supporting CSS files are written and loaded. I can write CSS code into 'override_styles.css' and internal style sheets. I can also include HTML and JavaScript into the header and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with your page.
Removing the width elements here:

```
<div id="sevariationlist_child" class="ddChild" style="height: 157px; z-index: 4999; display: block; width: 470px;"> <!--REMOVE WIDTH -->
```

and here:

```
.dd .ddChild {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 336px !important;/*REMOVE THIS*/
}
```

Then apply the width here:

```
.dd .ddChild a.selected {
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 500px; /*Visible width*/
}
```

I found this out using FireBug and modifying the CSS in there.  If you don't already use this, I highly recommend it.

Comment: RacerNerd, Thank you! Your solution was perfect. You found all of the conflicting !important tags and other specified widths. I was able to over-write them in my code and now the page displays like it was supposed to. Thank you so much to all of your for your time and effort! :)

Comment: Glad to help.  Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#sevarationlist_msdd .ddChild {
    width:436px !important;
}
```

With the id selector for the parent being more specific, it should override the existing `!important` width set to `336px` (see the picture below). hell, you might even get away with `width:auto !important;` instead, which will save headaches if the width is different in the future for some reason.

[image]

Comment: I was headed for the same answer, though !important should be a last resort. Find out what's setting the width in your JavaScript and fix that instead.

Comment: the `!important` bit was because there was another `!important` declaration in the CSS. you will need that to override (I don't like it either, but it is what it is). picture to show what i mean has been added.

Comment: PlantTheIdea, great suggestion, and you are definitely on the right track. I tried your solution, but unfortunately it did not work. Thank you!